# cURL set retry timeout in milliseconds

Tags: linux, unix, curl, connection-timeout

I need retry send timeout in milliseconds
connect-timeout is work by milliseconds but retry only work in seconds and error :

> expected a proper numerical parameter

all parameter retry only work by second

```
curl --retry 5 \
     --retry-delay 0 \
     --retry-max-time 40 \
     'http://your_url'
```

Comment: That's just the way `curl` works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behaviour of curl, it is open-source so you can fork it and do what you want with it.  It looks like the value in the code (which stores a long int converted from the string supplied on the command line) is multiplied by 1000 to convert it into milliseconds where it is used, see:

https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/308c243db5b7425b454a981d4c0eb7bfac374b8b/src/tool_operate.c#L433

so you could try removing the `*1000L` from this line in your own fork, build that, and see whether the number that you specify is now treated as a number in milliseconds.